# cannot run R error loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: wrong ELF class:ELFCLASS32

Tags: r, rstudio

I just trying to upgrade RStudio using "Check for update" on the "Help" menu of RStudio for Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. After downloading it from Rstudio download page and install the newest version, I'm unable to run RStudio. Then I check by command line by typing "R", but the console returns to this result -> *error loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: wrong ELF class:ELFCLASS32*

I already try to reinstall it from r-base to reinstalling RStudio 64bit. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can see is that it can't find your 64bit libraries ... 
So maybe in the RStudio update process, a library got removed and it now fails ... I'd try to check if the libblas is 64bit and if not, install the 64bit libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libblas3gf
sudo apt-get install libblas-doc
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
```

Comment: unfortunately after trying to install all those packages (libblas3gf; libblas-doc; and libblas-dev) the problem still occur. But after I try to install libblas3 instead, it just back to normal. thank you anyway ElGus!

Comment: `maybe in the RStudio update process` sounds cool